# Total sum of dynamic table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Good morning, everyone.

I have a problem, I new to javascript and jquery, and I have to use a dynamic table for a jewerly store, adding rows, delete rows, and multiplying the price for the quantity of the items. I already can multiply quality by price, but I can't get the grand total of all items. This is my code:

```
 function addRow(tableID) { 

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name="chkbox[]";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='codigo[]' name='codigo[]'>";

     var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='descripcion[]'>";

     var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell4.innerHTML =  "<input type='text' step='any' class='cantidad' style='height='50px' width='40px'' id='cantidad' min='1' onchange='calculate(this);' value='0' name='cantidad[]' oninput='calculate()' />";

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell5.innerHTML = "<input type='text' step='any' min='0' value='0' class='precio' id='precio' name='precio[]' onchange='calculate(this);' />";

     var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    cell6.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='total' value='0' class='total' name='total[]' />";

    }

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

This is for multiplying price by quantity

```
   function calculate(x)
 {

var myRow = x.parentNode.parentNode
myRow.cells[5].innerHTML = parseFloat(myRow.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0].value)*parseFloat(myRow.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0].value);
}
```

And this is my html

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Agregar Producto" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Borrar Producto" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<form id="myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  ?>" method="post">

<TABLE width="425" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="98"></th>
<th width="94">CODIGO</th>
<th width="94">DESCRIPCION</th>
<th width="84">CANTIDAD</th>
<th width="121">PRECIO</th>
<th width="121">TOTAL</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="dataTable">

</tbody>
</TABLE>
```

So, my question is, is there a way to obtain the grand total of this script? I tried many scripts, and adapted to my code, but non of them seem to work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: deleting/adding/multiplying all work ok right now?  can you provide some HTML with rows added?

Comment: Yes, they do. How can I do that? I kinda don't understand what you are asking, but I've added at least ten rows, and the all do the multiplying aspect. The same goes for adding and deleting. Though using the jfiddle, doesn't work, I don't know why, but, on my webpage, all of them work.


https://jsfiddle.net/qjh6s401/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible down and dirty solution
I modified the functions and it seems to work for me now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this is added just to pre-populate some rows
  addRow2('dataTable');
  addRow2('dataTable');
  addRow2('dataTable');
  addRow2('dataTable');
  

  
  $(".chkall").click(function() {
    if ($(".chkall").is(':checked')) {
      $("#dataTable input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
      });

    } else {
      $("#dataTable input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
      });
    }
  });


  $('.get_total, .g_total').click(function(e) {
    g_total = 0;
    $('input.total').each(function() {
      g_total += eval($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(g_total);
    $('.g_total').html(g_total);
  })
  $('input.total').on('change', function() {
    g_total = 0;
    $('input.total').each(function() {
      g_total += eval($(this).val());
      $('.g_total').html(g_total);
    })
  })
})

function grandTotal(){
  g_total = 0;
    $('input.total').each(function() {
      g_total += eval($(this).val());
      $('.g_total').html(g_total);
    })
}


function addRow2(tableid) {
  var table = $('#' + tableid);
  rowCount = table.children().length;
  //console.log(table.children().length);
  newrow = '<tr class="dataRow"><td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" class="remove"></td><td><input type="text" name="codigo[]"></td><td><input type="text" name="descripcion[]"></td><td><input type="text" step="any" class="cantidad" min="1" onchange="calc2($(this))" name="cantidad[]"></td><td><input type="text" step="any" min="0" value="0" class="precio" name="precio[]" onchange="calc2($(this));"></td><td><input type="text"  value="0" class="total" name="total[]"></td></tr>';
  table.append(newrow);
}



function calc2(_row) {
  row = _row.closest('.dataRow');
  //console.log();
  //
  qty = row.find('.cantidad').val();
  price = row.find('.precio').val();
  total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);
  console.log( 'qty:'+ qty +' * price:'+price + ' = '+total);
  row.closest('.dataRow').find('.total').val(total);
  grandTotal();
}



function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```css
.g_total {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.cantidad,
.precio,
.total {
  /*
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;*/
  text-align: center;
}
.cantidad {
  width: 84px;
}
.codigo,
.descripcion {
  width: 54px
}
.precio,
.total {
  width: 121px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<INPUT type="button" value="Agregar Producto" onClick="addRow2('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Borrar Producto" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<input type="button" class="get_total" value="Get Total" /><span class="g_total"></span>
<form id="myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  ?>" method="post">



  <TABLE border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkall">
        </th>
        <th class="codigo">CODIGO</th>
        <th class="descripcion">DESCRIPCION</th>
        <th class="cantidad">CANTIDAD</th>
        <th class="precio">PRECIO</th>
        <th class='total'>TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="dataTable">

    </tbody>
  </TABLE>
```

Comment: Weird, I try adding this code, but, it won't show on my page. I added everything, and it won't even show the 4 rows that are added automatically, even if I add the library of the jquery. It works here, (though it says that the g_total is 0, even though I put different numbers.

Comment: are you seeing any error in your console/inspector?

Comment: I just noticed another problem that you may have... you cannot set the **id** attribute for multiple items on the page to be the same. I have made assumptions that the rest of your code/functions as intended

Comment: Fixed it, it was some libraries and functions that I wasn't using, now, I can see the console box, but, the result is 0, even though I put different values.

Comment: so what do you have different from the snippet here?

Comment: your calculate function is removing the input elements where the grand total function is looking for the inputs and adding them up.  in my example i am just entering the values in the total input and it calculates. you will need to modify your functions to make sure it sets the value of the input not the html of the td

Comment: Nothing, I have everything like that. Which is weird, but, seeing the snippet right now, I can't see the total, in the console menu, it doesn't show anything, and in the log that's in the bottom of the snippet it just says
ready
{
  "message": "TypeError: x is undefined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 96,
  "colno": 7
}

Comment: like I stated before i made assumptions about your functions working but they are not integrating with what I did to calc total. I am working on it now but may have to set it aside in a bit if i don't finish it

Comment: It semes that you worked on it, it looks great. Thanks a lot. Now I just need to know how to do the autocomplete, which is also giving me headaches. Thanks a lot, man.

Comment: what do you mean autocomplete?

Comment: Thanks, since I'm new in this page, I didn't know you have to do that LOL, there. The autocomplete is for the products I have in a bd, for when I write the code (codigo), it'll automatically put the description and the price of the item.

Comment: Does bd= database

Comment: Yeah, sorry, spanish term, bd=db.